# Classification of singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to classify the singularities (essential, removable, pole) for the following functions :

$$f(z)=\frac{\cos(z^{1/2})}{z^{1/2}}$$

$$g(z)=e^{z/(1-z)}$$

However I am not sure I understood very well the difference between the types of singular points and the methods to use for $f$ and $g$. 
I would appreciate some help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For $f$, once you have fixed a branch of $z^{1/2}$ there are *no* **isolated** singularities.

For $g$, either find the Laurent series as suggested by Sucharita, or you can also argue like this

$$\lim_{x\to 1^+} e^{x/(1-x)} = 0 \qquad\lim_{x\to 1^-} e^{x/(1-x)} = +\infty$$

(taking $x$ real) which shows that $|g|$ is unbounded near $z=1$, but $\lim_{z\to 1} |g(z)| \neq \infty$. Hence $z=1$ is neither removable nor a pole, so it must be an essential singularity.

Comment: For$f$ I don't see why after fixing a branch we have no singularity, could you perhaps explain a bit more detailed? What happens at $z=0$? Thank you

Comment: Because I think at infinity we have a singularity. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @WhatsMyName I didn't say that $f$ has no singularities, I said it has no *isolated* ones. For the comment about singularities at infinity, $g$ does not have one ($\lim_{z\to\infty} g(z) = e^{-1}$) and the singularity of $f$ at $\infty$ is not isolated either.

Answer (score 0):

$g(z)=e^{z/(1-z)}=1+z/(1-z)+z^2/(1-z)^2+...$. Thus the function has an essential singularity at $z=1$, since we know that if $f(z)$ is expanded in Lorent expansion, then singularities can be easily classified.